# Can application services call other application services within a bounded context in DDD?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

Domain events are a great way to propagate that something happened so that something else can happen later. As I understand it, it's great to use domain events across bounded contexts.

Let's say we are creating a Q and A site like Stack Overflow. There are `users` that post `questions`, and questions can be `closed`.

Here are some possible commands in such an application:

- Ask question
- Close question
- Ban user

Domain requirements state that if a user is banned, all their questions must be closed.

When a fraud detection service detects that a user is a fraud, the user should be banned and all his questions closed. Can this `fraud detection service` call the `ban user service`, which in turn calls the `close all of user's questions` service?

We wouldn't want to duplicate all the "closing" logic we already made. Is it only recommended to dispatch events like "UserBannedEvent", and have a listener call the `close all of user's questions` application service? Or can one just call another?

Answer (score 1):

Domain events is a good way to trigger side effects on aggregates. It allows you to create a fine-grained and decoupled implementation by segregating responsibilities. That is, if you want to adhere to DDD.

You might ask "why not commands, then?". Well, you can use commands, but it's semantically wrong is this case (in my opinion). Commands are about things that you want to happen, but fraud detection just happens and you should declare it as such.

You may run commands as side effects, triggered by events if you want (be careful not to over-engineer).

> Is it only recommended to dispatch events like "UserBannedEvent", and have a listener call the close all of user's questions application service? Or can one just call another?

1. You run `DetectFraudCommand` command to detect fraud
2. `fraud detection service` generates `FraudDetectedEvent` event
3. `ban user service` gets triggered by `FraudDetectedEvent` and calls `CloseQuestionsCommand` command
4. `close all of user's questions service` bans user

That makes it loosely coupled and it clearly describes business logic. Also, it scales better: you can hook up any other listener for `FraudDetectedEvent` without ever touching `fraud detection service`, which isn't possible if you run commands directly.

It gets trickier if you need transactional consistency, but can be solved by appropriate event dispatcher design.

Here's a good relevant read on aggregate design by Vaughn Vernon: [link](https://dddcommunity.org/wp-content/uploads/files/pdf_articles/Vernon_2011_2.pdf).

Comment: Can you please clarify in your steps what is in the application level vs domain level? This still leaves some questions unanswered: per DDD, the domain layer should not be in control over its own persistence; it should be "orchestrated" by the application layer. So: if there is a business requirement "when a user is banned, all questions must be closed", when the event is triggered, if an application-level command picks it up, it can "orchestrate" closing questions, etc, but it's a *domain* requirement, thus in the wrong place, no? And if domain picks it up, it can't persist on its own.

Comment: "It gets trickier if you need transactional consistency, but can be solved by appropriate event dispatcher design." I am curious about this, as well. Can you please provide a reference or explanation on that?

Comment: Every step here describes domain layer logic, that's by design (meaning, per DDD). Of course actual implementation may use several layers. Commands are usually domain-level (as they are business intents), although command handlers might reside in application level. I usually follow this rule of thumb to determine domain-application boundary: if your business analyst can't understand whole business logic reading only domain layer stuff - it's bad design. So, application/infrastructure layer here would be event engine, for example. I hope I got your questiom right

Comment: Transactional consistency is a whole another discussion, but in short, most DDD adepts advice following eventual consistency as it's easier to scale (due to lesser contention, amount of locks, etc), but sometimes you really need strict serial execution and atomic persistence spanning several services or even domains - your design will lack in performance and scalability, but it might worth it in terms of business value